# Using rasters/features created at 10.0 in ArcGIS Desktop 9.3?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, raster, arcgis-9.3

I am tempted to go back to ArcGIS 9.3 from ArcGIS 10. For what I do, 9.3 is more efficent.

I know I cannot open ArcGIS 10 documents (maps, scenes) and layers in 9.3 unless saved as 9.3 file, but what about features and rasters I created in 10?

Can I add those into any 9.3 document?

Are there any issues that I should expect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you created updated versions of file geodatabases or layer files, you will need to save them as 9.3 versions to use them in 9.3.  10 added support for additional rasters that 9.3 can't use or use as well such as mg4 MrSid rasters..  See http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//016w00000032000000 for 10.1s.  You might also find some georeferenced rasters showing up oddly, most notably tifs.  See http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/31659-Problems-georeferencing-tiffs-in-arcmap-10